# create and view PDF document in C# and javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am starting a Web project in C# and javascript and I need to create and view PDF document. As an example, create and view a resume.

What library can I use to achieve the above.

Thanks for your help

Comment: itextsharp is the best widely used library for PDF in C# Refer link https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/d40a40/create-simple-pdf-file-using-itextsharp-library/

Comment: This question should be closed: From the [help/on-topic]: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Answer (score 2):

You can use iTextSharp to generate PDF's with C#.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/iTextSharp/

With this lib you can create the PDF.
then return it to the client and use it as you wish download or present (you can present it with iframe to the route that return the pdf)

Answer (score 0):

To render PDF using javascript you can use

Adobe Embed APIs: https://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/dcsdk_io/viewSDK/index.html

- Cloud-based
- Easy to integrate
- Lots of PDF features

Comment: Please don't post links as answers. Instead post a bit of code that shows how to apply your solution.